# How to run a Script on hosted Website in asp.net core?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have designed a website in asp.net, which redirects to another website. I want to track the click on that website through my website.
The problem is that how can i run my script on another website?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the other website allows you for CORS then you can open that website in an `IFrame` and run your scripts on top of it, otherwise there is no way you can do that. That would be a violation of CORS Policies.

Comment: I assume by "script" you're referring to some client-side JavaScript that performs your analytics? Do you control the output on both sites or only the ASP.NET site that you designed? There are a handful of approaches to click-through tracking, but they really depend on the answers to those questions.

Comment: Scripts here refers to the way through which i came to know that the asp.net website is the source of reaching the other website. As far as the control is concerned i only have only have access to the other website